# solana-bankrun warnig of jest open handle CustomGC

Tags: solana-bankrun, jest

I experiment with `solana-bankrun` (https://github.com/kevinheavey/solana-bankrun) and `anchor-bankrun` tooling for testing my contract.

When I use `jest` for tests and I set up the `--detect-open-handles` to true (`detectOpenHandles: true`) the test ends with jest warning about opened handles.

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  CustomGC
```

Do I miss some closing of the bankrun processing in my test?

Comment: I spent awhile trying to figure this out, thinking it was a bug in the base `solana-program-test`, but couldn't resolve it at that level. This happens in all of the tests, which makes me think that there's some other issue in the library. You may want to open an issue directly with the repo